# Disappearing Elements

Tags: code-golf, string, array

Given a string `S` and a list of indices `X`, modify `S` by removing the element at each index of `S` while using that result as the new value of `S`.

For example, given `S = 'codegolf'` and `X = [1, 4, 4, 0, 2]`,

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7  |
c o d e g o l f  |  Remove 1
c d e g o l f    |  Remove 4
c d e g l f      |  Remove 4
c d e g f        |  Remove 0
d e g f          |  Remove 2
d e f
```

Your task is to perform this process, collect the values of `S` after each operation, and display each on a newline in order. The final answer would be

```
S = 'codegolf'
X = [1, 4, 4, 0, 2]

Answer:

codegolf
cdegolf
cdeglf
cdegf
degf
def
```

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so make your code as short as possible.
- You may assume that the values in `X` are always valid indices for `S`, and you may use either 0-based or 1-based indexing.
- The string will only contain `[A-Za-z0-9]`
- Either `S` or `x` may by empty. If `S` is empty, it follows that `x` must also be empty.
- You may also take `S` as a list of characters instead of a string.
- You may either print the output or return a list of strings. Leading and trailing whitespace is acceptable. Any form of output is fine as long as it is easily readable.

### Test Cases

```
S = 'abc', x = [0]
'abc'
'bc'

S = 'abc', x = []
'abc'

S = 'abc', x = [2, 0, 0]
'abc'
'ab'
'b'
''

S = '', x = []
''

S = 'codegolfing', x = [10, 9, 8, 3, 2, 1, 0]
'codegolfing'
'codegolfin'
'codegolfi'
'codegolf'
'codgolf'
'cogolf'
'cgolf'
'golf'
```

Comment: May we take `S` as a list of characters?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Sure, I'll add that in the spec.

Comment: May we print as a list of characters?

Comment: Can we skip the first item (the original string) in the output?

Comment: @ETHproductions No, the output should be the original string first, and then each string that results from deleting a character. So the output should contain `len(x)+1` strings.

Comment: Can we, as Erik asked, output arrays/lists of individual characters?

Comment: Yes, using list of characters instead of strings for input and output is fine.

Comment: Will there be strings with indices > 9? (IE double digits)

Comment: @nmjcman101 Yes, I'll add an test case for that.

Comment: If all results are printed, may the program then exit with an error?

Comment: Third test case, should it not be: `S = 'abc', x = [2, 0, 0]` remove c to leave `ab` then remove `a` to leave `b` then remove `b` to leave empty string?

Comment: @streetster You're right, I made a typo.

Comment: I feel I might be *really* pushing it here, which is why I figured it best to ask first: would outputting one, single, comma-separated string be allowed? e.g., for your example, `"c,o,d,e,g,o,l,f,c,d,e,g,o,l,f,c,d,e,g,l,f,c,d,e,g,f,d,e,g,f,d,e,f"`

Comment: @Shaggy I don't think it is readable, for example if the input was `'aaaa'` and `[0,0,0,0]`, your output would be `a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,''`

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>57</s> <s>50</s> <s>48</s> <s>45</s> 42 bytes

Takes the string as an array of individual characters, outputs an array containing a comma separated string of the original followed by a subarray of comma separated strings for each step.

```js
s=>a=>[s+"",a.map(x=>s.splice(x,1)&&s+"")]
```

- 3 bytes saved thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)
  suggesting I abuse the loose output spec more than I already was, which led me to abusing it even more for another 3 byte saving.

---

### Test it

```js
o.innerText=JSON.stringify((f=

s=>a=>[s+"",a.map(x=>s.splice(x,1)&&s+"")]

)([...i.value="codegolf"])(j.value=[1,4,4,0,2]));oninput=_=>o.innerText=JSON.stringify(f([...i.value])(j.value.split`,`))
```

```css
label,input{font-family:sans-serif;font-size:14px;height:20px;line-height:20px;vertical-align:middle}input{margin:0 5px 0 0;width:100px;}
```

```html
<label for=i>String: </label><input id=i><label for=j>Indices: </label><input id=j><pre id=o>
```

---

### Explanation

We take the two inputs via parameters `s` (the string array) and `a` (the integer array) in currying syntax, meaning we call the function with `f(s)(a)`.

We build a new array and start it off with the original `s`. However, as the `splice` method we'll be using later on modifies an array, we need to make a copy of it, which we can do by converting it to a string (simply append an empty string).

To generate the subarray, we `map` over the integer array `a` (where `x` is the current integer) and, for each element, we `splice` 1 element from `s`, beginning at index `x`. We return the modified `s`, again making a copy of it by converting it to a string.

Comment: Because _any form of output is fine as long as it is easily readable_, I suppose that one should also be acceptable: `s=>a=>[s+'',...a.map(x=>s.splice(x,1)&&s+'')]`

Comment: Nice one, @Arnuald - I wouldn't have thought to push it that far, even given that spec.

Answer (score 8):

### Haskell, <s>38</s> 33 bytes

```
s#i=take i s++drop(i+1)s
scanl(#)
```

Straight forward: repeatedly take the elements before and after index i, rejoin them and collect the results.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYuxDkAwGAZ3T/EFA2kHxNonEUOjxR/V4vf@xUgiN97drHmxzsXIGalTLxYEFsIcYStI1CUnu@JBe1dkZVw1eSiYkADbQf5Ejh3pEIydghtTdLVsbyrZ9L/Jv6nki0/4rPEC)

Edit: @Lynn saved 5 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: `s#i=take i s++drop(i+1)s` is actually shorter, saving 5 bytes.

Comment: Nope, you’re at 33 now — don’t forget that the TIO snippet has `q=` in there ^^;

Comment: Yep, you're right.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 43 bytes

```python
s,i=input()
for i in i+[0]:print s;s.pop(i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcrBCoAgEATQe1@xN5WWsOhU9CXiqbIWQpe0Q19vGBEMb2AYvtMefJdzRJrI85Wkqlw4gYA8UG20HfgknyCOseHAklR28nvi1yobI2aBIEJhKayF7d@OghMWwbQI/RuN0Fn7AA)

> Any form of output is fine as long as it is easily readable.

So this prints as lists of chars.

Comment: Nice, but why did you choose the notation abuse `for i in i+[0]`?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Because that way the last line is shown. (and the reason I posted separately in first place)

Comment: No, not `+[0]`, I am talking about `for i in i`. [`for k in i` is equivalent](https://tio.run/##PcgxCsMwDIXhPafQJomakIZO6VGMpyZu1RRZxM7Q0zs4lMLje/Dbt7ySjrXOS4RI2QlPHcS0wQqiIBc/hMk20YLYv5MoZb7n3pLRyjWSqO2F2P2eq8cHOsDUmBtL4/lvn0bE0Pmrg9u5wcEYDg).

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Because I like it that way...

Comment: Ok, just curious... Maybe it was a trick I didn't know of :)

Comment: The spec for the output is very loose so you should be OK submitting the 43 byte version. The output format is similar to my solution's.

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 bytes

```
åjV uV
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=5WpWIHVW&input=WzEsNCw0LDAsMl0gImNvZGVnb2xmIg==)

#### Explanation

```
UåjV uV   Implicit: U = array of integers, V = string
Uå        Cumulatively reduce U by
  j         removing the item at that index in the previous value,
   V        with an initial value of V.
     uV   Push V to the beginning of the result.
```

Alternatively:

```
uQ åjV

UuQ       Push a quotation mark to the beginning of U.
    å     Cumulatively reduce by
     j      removing the item at that index in the previous value,
      V     with an initial value of V.
```

This works because removing the item at index `"` does nothing and so returns the original string.

Answer (score 6):

### [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
G§+oh↑↓
```

Takes first the string, then (1-based) indices.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3/3Qcu38jEdtEx@1Tf7//79SYlJySmpaeobS/2gTHUMdIx2jWAA)

### Explanation

```
G§+oh↑↓
G        Scan from left by function:
           Arguments are string, say s = "abcde", and index, say i = 3.
      ↓    Drop i elements: "de"
     ↑     Take i elements
   oh      and drop the last one: "ab"
 §+        Concatenate: "abde"
         Implicitly print list of strings on separate lines.
```

Comment: How do I use an empty list of indices `x`?

Comment: @miles You have to specify the type, [like this](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3/3Qcu38jEdtEx@1Tf7//79SYlJySmpaeobS/@hYKx8/AA).

Comment: I see, thanks. I'm not very familiar with either Haskell or Husk.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 bytes

This could be shortened to [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P1EnyTYzr6C0REOTKy2/SCFTITNPIUk72iDWqqAoM69EIdE6Ua8gv0AjU/P//2ilZCUdpXwgTgHiVCBOh/JzgDhNKVZHIdpQR8EEjAx0FIxiAQ), as @LuisMendo pointed out, but that's already @ErktheOutgolfer's solution.

```python
a,b=input();print a
for i in b:a.pop(i);print a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P1EnyTYzr6C0REPTuqAoM69EIZErLb9IIVMhM08hySpRryC/QCMTLvf/f7RSspKOUj4QpwBxKhCnQ/k5QJymFKujEG2oo2ACRgY6CkaxAA)

Comment: `\`a\`[2::5]` instead `''.join(a)`

Comment: @Rod How does than work?

Comment: `repr` and string spliting, works good to turn a list of *characters* into a string, `\`a\`[1::3]` can also be used with a list of *digits*

Comment: @Rod I know what they are, I don't understand how `::5` works here :P

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder well then study string slicing ;) basically it takes every 5th char starting from the 2nd

Comment: It will get every 5th character, starting from the 3rd, the list repr will be `['a', 'b', 'c']` (note the space next to the comma), so it will be the characters

Comment: [4 bytes off](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P1EnyTYzr6C0REOTKy2/SCFTITNPIUk72iDWqqAoM69EIdE6Ua8gv0AjU/P//2ilZCUdpXwgTgHiVCBOh/JzgDhNKVZHIdpQR8EEjAx0FIxiAQ) getting rid of the repeated `print`

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks, but unfortunately that's Erik's solution :P - Will mention though

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, 78 bytes

This is a curried lambda, from `int[]` to a consumer of [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/StringBuilder.html) or [`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/StringBuffer.html). Output is printed to standard out.

```java
l->s->{System.out.println(s);for(int i:l)System.out.println(s.delete(i,i+1));}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##bY8xT8MwEIXn9lecOsUisShiIiUDIDamjlUH4zjRpY5t2eegKspvD27aBVHphne6907v68QgCuuU6erT7OK3RglSixDgS6CBcb1yHgdBCgIJSscuBXgk1LyJRhJawz9vYrcnj6Z9i6hr5fN71ndrQuyV36Ghw7GqIH039IFBOKfEJQ2vcygqXVTj/hxI9dxG4otLmyywsrE@Swvgi2b3HLxWWpHKMMeHLWPlNK/KBHEluzEMFmvoE192bXw4gvBtYBfc1b9GPCl9zoz6gT@A2UbaWrVWNxvGuJBSOVpcCxuM2xyel3nM4WliqcW0nuZf)

Comment: Your second answer is a valid entry. Nothing forbids you to carefully select your input type as long as it makes sense. I've several times already taken even `Stream`s as input and got very nice answers. Actually, nearly all golfing languages use streams equivalent internally. So by selecting your input, you just level a tad. +1 nonetheless

Comment: Maybe you're right. I think I tend to be more conservative than most about these things. I'll switch to the second solution.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
v=ā0m0yǝÏ},
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/zPZIo0GuQeXxuYf7a3X@/4821DEBQgMdo1iuaKVkJR2lfCBOAeJUIE6H8nOAOE0pFgA)

```
v           # For each index:
 =          #   Print without popping
  ā         #   Push range(1, len(a) + 1)
   0m       #   Raise each to the power of 0. 
            #   This gives a list of equal length containing all 1s
     0yǝ    #   Put a 0 at the location that we want to remove
        Ï   #   Keep only the characters that correspond to a 1 in the new list
         }, # Print the last step
```

Comment: The first line isn't there. Oh, and not sure if you can print like that.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer `Any form of output is fine as long as it is easily readable`

Comment: I can save some bytes then...

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 70 bytes

```
(s=#;For[t=1,t<=Length@#2,Print@s;s=StringDrop[s,{#2[[t]]+1}];t++];s)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvtfo9hW2dotvyi6xNZQp8TG1ic1L70kw0HZSCegKDOvxKHYutg2uATITHcpyi@ILtapVjaKji6JjdU2rI21LtHWjrUu1lT7D1as4JAWrZScn5Kanp@TpqSjUG2oYwKEBjpGtbH/AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>46</s> 32 bytes

```r
function(S,X)Reduce(`[`,-X,S,,T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcgxCoAwDAXQ3WNkSuA7qDh6CesglEKhNiKIFW3PX@Vt76k6VS1XyEe62GCVOW4lRPbWo11hgEWq8puf9z6PzBTSFvd0KoFIrO2cQ@Ae46/DINIoE/0lUj8)

Takes input as a list of characters and `X` is 1-based. `Reduce` is the R equivalent of `fold`, the function in this case is `[` which is subset. Iterates over `-X` because negative indexing in R removes the element, and `init` is set to `S`, with `accum=TRUE` so we accumulate the intermediate results.

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 80 bytes

```r
function(S,X,g=substring)Reduce(function(s,i)paste0(g(s,0,i-1),g(s,i+1)),X,S,,T)
```

2-argument function, takes `X` 1-indexed. Takes `S` as a string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYuxDoUgEAT/xeou7ktEY@lPPC1sFYFcYsAIfD9iY7aZyWTvYqdis9dJgqcZK9wU8x7TLd7x3xxZG/p6hPC1xWQ6clU6yE8xXpRWMdf3DCxcLDU6HMaF0zbQ1GOsUxiYywM)

Comment: Very smart to use `Reduce` here. Well done!

Answer (score 3):

## q/kdb+, <s>27</s> 10 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{x _\0N,y}
```

**Examples:**

```
q){x _\0N,y}["codegolf";1 4 4 0 2]
"codegolf"
"cdegolf"
"cdeglf"
"cdegf"
"degf"
"def"
q){x _\0N,y}["abc";0]
"abc"
"bc"
q){x _\0N,y}["abc";()]
"abc"
q){x _\0N,y}["abc";2 0 0]
"abc"
"ab"
,"b"
""    
q){x _\0N,y}["";()]
""
```

**Explanation:**

Takes advantage of the [converge](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#converge-iterate) functionality `\` as well as drop `_`.

```
{x _\0N,y}
{        } / lambda function, x and y are implicit variables
     0N,y  / join null to the front of list (y), drop null does nothing
   _\      / drop over (until result converges) printing each stage
 x         / the string (need the space as x_ could be a variable name)
```

**Notes:**

If we didn't need to print the original result, this would be **2** bytes in `q`:

```
q)_\["codegolfing";10 9 8 3 2 1 0]
"codegolfin"
"codegolfi"
"codegolf"
"codgolf"
"cogolf"
"cgolf"
"golf"
```

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>94</s> 84 bytes

```powershell
param($s,$x)$a=[Collections.Generic.list[char]]$s;$x|%{-join$a;,$a|% r*t $_};-join$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LchBCsIwEADAr@xhS1tZS6sXJQiCBx9RioQY28ialCRgwfr29eIcZw5vG9NkmUVmHfWrwkS41KhP/SUwW5Nd8Km5Wm@jMw27lHsz6TgMmBQua/HZPoPzqBWhXguImwx4@6r/ikhpwt2OgR/Oj6Wcq64lOBIcCPYEO4KOoK1/)

Takes input `$s` as a string and `$x` as an explicit array. We then create `$a` based on `$s` as a list.

Arrays in PowerShell are fixed size (for our purposes here), so we need to use the lengthy `[System.Collections.Generic.list]` type in order to get access to the `.removeAt()` function, which does exactly what it says on the tin.

I sacrificed 10 bytes to include two `-join` statements to make the output pretty. OP has stated that outputting a list of chars is fine, so I could output just `$a` rather than `-join$a`, but that's really ugly in my opinion.

*Saved 10 bytes thanks to briantist.*

Comment: You can leave off `System` and just use `[Collections.Generic.list[char]]`. To keep it pretty without sacrificing bytes, you  can put the last `-join$a` in the footer in TIO.

Comment: I think you can also save 3 bytes by changing `$a.removeat($_)` to `,$a|% r*t $_`.

Comment: @briantist Thanks for those - I always forget to remove `System` from the class name. Sadly the last `-join$a` is necessary for the code, so I can't move it to the footer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 33 bytes

```hs
scanl(\s i->take i s++drop(i+1)s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcJLCoAgFAXQrVykgWJBRtPaSDUQP/XINHrt3@Kcw/IZUqo1TuxsTnJlUDe/9gwgsNb@KbckbRSrelnKmHA/lF80iBCu@LCXFAUW046/vh22@gE)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```
=svõyǝ=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/ftrjs8NbK43Nt//9Pzk9JTc/PSeOKNtQxAUIDHaNYAA)

---

```
=s        # Print original string, swap with indices.
  v       # Loop through indices...
   õyǝ    # Replace current index with empty string.
```

-2 thanks to idea from @ETHProductions.

Comment: This doesn't print anything if `x` is empty.

Comment: @Riley fixed. (#ETHProductions fixed.)

Comment: Couldn't you just do `=sv""yǝ=` or something similar instead of replacing with a newline and then removing the newline?

Comment: @ETHproductions `õ` also works :)

Comment: Well I don't know 05AB1E, haha

Comment: @ETHproductions [now you do :P](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/info.txt)

Comment: Why is there a second `=` in your code but not your explanation?

Comment: @isaacg typo. '= # print char'.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 50 bytes

- Takes in string and list of indices

```python
s,i=input()
for j in i+[0]:print s;s=s[:j]+s[j+1:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcKxCoAgEADQva@4zUKHlCbDLzmcKuskVDwb@nqDHq@87crJ9M6KHKXytHEaQq4QgRKQxNnbUik14JUdo41eMkapre9dbHk/znwHoVArWP6zAuM/)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 99 bytes

```c
j;f(s,a,i)char*s;int*a;{puts(s);for(j=0;j<i;j++){memmove(s+a[j],s+a[j]+1,strlen(s)-a[j]);puts(s);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7NCsMgEIRfRXLSuIGktKdtniTkINakSozFtb1Int0m/YGBgYFvZnQza12Kw4kTKLBC31WsCe2aaoX58UzESeAUInd9i@5q0Ukpsjfeh5fhJNXgRvia7IBSXMy6I80RCPwXbFvxyq5c5GOA0TD2lQ43M4dlqo41pvYod8DOH7XATtvv1GXHyxs)

Takes the string, array, and the length of the array.

Comment: [91 bytes](https://tio.run/##LU5BDsIgEPwK9gQtJGr0hH1J0wOupUIqNCweDKlfRzBNJtmZzezsgJgBcrZSU@SKGwZPFVqUxsVWyaR9oLY/rO@IFJm0NyN3zu7g1w9F8VWD7bqRY1dIGTEskysGUSWTW34p4yhLNZjgMPYN@Mc0@0U39QtRZZVOnFz@OHJy3vYy13r9Aw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
ii"t[]@(
```

Indexing is 1-based.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PzNTqSQ61kHj/3/15PyU1PT8nDR1rmgjHQVTMDLUUTCOBQA) Or [verify the test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D8zU6kkOtZB43@suq6urnqES8h/9cSkZHWuaMNYLigLzjDWUTAEIiAfJAoA).

#### Explanation

```
i      % Input string. Input has to be done explicitly so that the string
       % will be displayed even if the row vector of indices is empty
i      % Input row vector of indices
"      % For each
  t    %   Duplicate current string
  []   %   Push empty array
  @    %   Push current index
  (    %   Assignment indexing: write [] to string at specified index
       % End (implicit). Display stack (implicit)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 58 bytes

```
¶\d+
¶¶1$&$*
+1`(?=.*¶¶.(.)*)(((?<-1>.)*).(.*)¶)¶.*
$2$3$4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P//0LaYFG2uQ9sObTNUUVPR4tI2TNCwt9XTAonoaehpamlqaGjY2@ga2oHYQBEtzUPbgEhPi0vFSMVYxeT//@T8lNT0/Jy0zLx0LkMDLksuCy5jLiMuQy4DAA) Explanation:

```
¶\d+
```

Match the indices (which are never on the first line, so are always preceded by a newline).

```
¶¶1$&$*
```

Double-space the indices, convert to unary, and add 1 (because zeros are hard in Retina).

```
+1`
```

Repeatedly change the first match, which is always the current value of the string.

```
   (?=.*¶¶.(.)*)
```

Retrieve the next index in `$#1`.

```
                (           .    ¶)
```

Capture the string, including the `$#1`th character and one newline.

```
                 ((?<-1>.)*) (.*)
```

Separately capture the prefix and suffix of the `$#1`th character of the string.

```
                                   ¶.*
```

Match the index.

```
$2$3$4
```

Replace the string with itself and the index with the prefix and suffix of the `$#1`th character.

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>87</s> <s>87</s> <s>74</s> 70 bytes

```cs
S=>I=>{for(int i=0;;S=S.Remove(I[i++],1))System.Console.WriteLine(S);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5BS8NAFITv@yuWnnbpNiR6UbYJiMVS0It78BByCNvX8iB5W/dtWyTkt8coKCJzmoGZbzyvfIgwnRnpKN0HJ@it@OuyZ6T3f9Fj6DrwCQNxtgWCiN4KanvgU@tB0iB81zLL0yA4tQm9fDqTX3OK84h5@G6ukVLdVJXcyHJyZbUrq@EQoppjiWVurStd9gp9uIDa1bhcNqbQ@vcAcegge4uYYD4Iymk7TvYHdwm4ly8tktKD2KiFD3s4hu4w4xdaEVzrZihyc2/uzK25MYXJR23F@KXpEw)

Just goes to show that recursion isn't always the best solution. This is actually shorter than my original invalid answer. Still prints to STDOUT rather than returning, which is necessary because it ends with an error.

-4 bytes thanks to TheLethalCoder

Comment: Per a recent meta consensus (that I can't find) recursive lambdas in C# are disallowed unless you specify what they compile to in the byte count. Therefore, a full method is shorter in this case. I am downvoting until this is fixed, let me know when.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I may not agree with the consensus, but it does seem to be [consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13225/byte-count-for-named-recursive-lambda-expressions-in-c-answers). I've updated my answer.

Comment: [70 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY5BS8NAFITv@yuWnnbpNiR6UbYJiMVS0It78BByCNvX8iB5W/dtWyTkt8coKCJzmoGZbzyvfIgwnRnpKN0HJ@it@OuyZ6T3f9Fj6DrwCQNxtgWCiN4KanvgU@tB0iB81zLL0yA4tQm9fDqTX3OK84h5@G6ukVLdVJXcyHJyZbUrq@EQoppjiWVurStd9gp9uIDa1bhcNqbQ@vcAcegge4uYYD4Iymk7TvYHdwm4ly8tktKD2KiFD3s4hu4w4xdaEVzrZihyc2/uzK25MYXJR23F@KXpEw). Use currying and move one statement into the loop to stop needing the loop braces.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Ah, so THAT's how you use currying in C#! I knew it was shorter for exactly two arguments, but it always ended up complaining about some part of my syntax. Thanks for the improvements

Comment: No worries and yeah the first one must always be a `Func` that returns the other `Func`, `Action`, `Predicate`,...

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 8 bytes

```
.u.DNYEz
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.u.DNYEz&input=codegolf%0A%5B1%2C+4%2C+4%2C+0%2C+2%5D&debug=0)

Reduce, starting with the string and iterating over the list of indices, on the deletion function.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>54</s> 58 bytes

```powershell
param($s,$x),-1+$x|%{$z=$_;$i=0;-join($s=$s|?{$z-ne$i++})}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcnRCsIgFADQX7kPN6Z4Ba2XYkj9xxghyzbDdOhDo7Zvt53XM6ePy2VyIdQ622zfDAvhwklqgct6@OHX4L1Fb1QrX8nH/Q2W9bqHjA69EBvfaq2sGyabu75vhvRwYwpPH8eG1xvTiuBCcCY4ERwJNIHifw)

### Explanation

Takes input as a char array (`[char[]]`).

Iterates through the array of indices (`$x`) plus an injected first element of `-1`, then for each one, assigns the current element to `$z`, initializes `$i` to `0`, then iterates through the array of characters (`$s`), returning a new array of only the characters whose index (`$i`) does not equal (`-ne`) the current index to exclude (`$z`). This new array is assigned back to `$s`, while simultaneously being returned (this happens when the assignment is done in parentheses). That returned result is `-join`ed to form a string which is sent out to the pipeline.

Injecting `-1` at the beginning ensures that the original string will be printed, since it's the first element and an index will never match `-1`.

Comment: Very clever way of pulling out the appropriate indices.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 55 bytes (54 + "`-l`")

```perl
sub{print($s=shift);for(@_){substr$s,$_,1,"";print$s}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7NCoMwEAbveYol5GBgA9ofaAmWvolUa2xAjGTTk/jqTdPQ3irs6ZuB2bn34zEKAzVEerbL7O0UCkE1PawJUhvni2sjl8QoeEEoGqyQc51FQesaNWPCqEvBO3fvBzcajlAhHPKVCDupWbaBK6W4/tq3tktiuQ3/k43517bT8Mmn7BnhhLBP/fxOCsWXm4N1E0U1vgE)

Comment: Nice! I came up with a very similar approach, but as a full program (using `-pa`) for 44 bytes: [`$_=<>;substr$_,shift@F,print,""while@F&&$_`](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tbGzrq4NKm4pEglXqc4IzOtxMFNp6AoM69ER0mpPCMzJ9XBTU1NJf7/f0MFEyA0UDDiSs5PSU3Pz0nj@pdfUJKZn1f8X7cgEQA)

Comment: Nice! Not sure you need the final `&&$_` since you can assume the input is valid (the list of indices can't be longer than the string). Using the return value of `print` as the number of characters is quite slick.

Comment: Ah, that's true! I didn't notice that part of the spec! I thought my answer was far too similar to yours to post separately though!

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 23 bytes

```
>@({&.>/\.&.|.@;<^:4"0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxga6VgoADE/@0cNKrV9Oz0Y/TU9Gr0HKxt4qxMlAw0/2tyKekpqKfZWqkr6CjUWimkFXNxpSZn5CuoJ@enpKbn56SpK6QpGCqYAKGBgtF/AA)

Comment: Brilliant use of negative boxing.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `o`, 4 bytes

```
(…n⟇
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJvIiwiIiwiKOKApm7in4ciLCIiLCJbMSwgNCwgNCwgMCwgMl1cbltcImNcIiwgXCJvXCIsIFwiZFwiLCBcImVcIiwgXCJnXCIsIFwib1wiLCBcImxcIiwgXCJmXCJdIl0=)

Prints lists of chars

```
(…n⟇ # 'o' flag forces output of the last value
(    # For every number in the list...
 …   # Print the string without popping
  n  # Get the current value
   ⟇ # Remove the char at the index
     # The result is printed on next iteration
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

Rule changes saved me 1 byte:

```
V+E0Q .(QN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P0zb1SBQQU8j0O///2ilZCUdpXwgTgHiVCBOh/JzgDhNKZYr2lBHwQSMDHQUjGIB)

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 11 bytes

```
V+E0sQ .(QN
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P0zb1aA4UEFPI9Dv//9opWQlHaV8IE4B4lQgTofyc4A4TSmWK9pQR8EEjAx0FIxiAQ)**

Comment: @miles isn't stderr output allowed by default?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I thought stderr output was ignored in that case...

Comment: @miles I will remove mine and flag it to a mod if we do not remove them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://tio.run/#python2), 54

```
X,S=input()
for a in X:
    print S
    S=S[:a]+S[a+1:]
print S
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P0In2DYzr6C0REOTKy2/SCFRITNPIcKKizPYNjjaKjFWOzg6UdvQKparoCgzr0Qh@P//aEMdBRMwMtBRMIrVUU/OT0lNz89JUwcA)

Comment: I only see the last string in the output.

Comment: I messed up... One moment...

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 12 bytes

```
òdt,GÙ@-|xHx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///CmlBId98MzHXRrKjwq/v83NNQxNNCx1DHRMdYx0jHU4UrOT0lNz89Jy8xLBwA)

This is 1-indexed, input is like:

```
11,10,9,4,3,2,1,
codegolfing
```

#### Explanation

```
ò              ' <M-r>ecursively until error
 dt,           ' (d)elete (t)o the next , (errors when no more commas)
    G          ' (G)oto the last line
     Ù         ' Duplicate it down
        |      ' Goto column ...
      @-       ' (deleted number from the short register)
         x     ' And delete the character there
          H    ' Go back home
           x   ' And delete the comma that I missed
```

Comment: How do I use an empty list of indices `x`?

Comment: @miles By adding a few bytes :).  Simply an empty first line will now work.  Would you be OK if I took lists with a trailing comma?  IE `1,2,3,`.  Empty list would be nothing, Singleton would be `1,`

Comment: Sure, you can use that input format.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 9 bytes

```
+⟪Seḥ+⟫⊣ṣ
```

<sup>I should really add a "delete at index" function...</sup>

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/X/vR/FXBqQ93LAUyVj/qWvxw5@L/qY/aOxSA4FHDHOfEnByFkoxUhbTSvOSSzPw8BSAC8TPzCkpLHjXMjfkPVJWcn5Kanp@TBuQrRBsqmAChgYJRLAA)

#### Explanation

```
+          Add the string to the list
 ⟪Seḥ+⟫⊣   Cumulatively reduce by this block:
  S         Split around index n
   e        Dump the list
    ḥ       Remove the first char of the second part
     +      Concatenate back together
        ṣ  Join the result with newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift 3](https://www.swift.org), 80 bytes

```swift
func f(l:[String],c:[Int]){var t=l;for i in c{print(t);t.remove(at:i)};print(t)}
```

**[Try it online!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/598df3ef19b65f016ddd76f4)**

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 8 bytes

```
+zm=z.Dz
```

[Test suite!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2Bzm%3Dz.Dz&input=%22codegolf%22%0A%5B1%2C+4%2C+4%2C+0%2C+2%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C+4%2C+4%2C+0%2C+2%5D%0Acodegolf%0A%5B0%5D%0Aabc%0A%5B%5D%0Aabc%0A%5B2%2C+0%2C+0%5D%0Aabc%0A%5B%5D%0A%0A%5B10%2C+9%2C+8%2C+3%2C+2%2C+1%2C+0%5D%0Acodegolfing%0A&debug=0&input_size=2)

## explanation

```
+zm=z.DzdQ    # implicit: input and iteration variable
  m      Q    # for each of the elements of the first input (the array of numbers, Q)
     .Dzd     # remove that index from the second input (the string, z)
   =z         # Store that new value in z
+z            # prepend the starting value
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL, <s>31</s> <s>30</s> 28 bytes

```
{⎕←⍺⋄⍵≡⍬:⍬⋄⍺[(⍳⍴⍺)~⊃⍵]∇1↓⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v9fPTk/JTU9PydNXaH6Ud/UR20THvXuetTd8qh366POhY9611gBMZi/K1rjUe/mR71bgEzNukddzUAlsY862g0ftU0GMmsVjBRMgdBQwfj/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>70</s> 65 bytes

As generic unnamed lambda, requiring `s` to be like `std::string` but `x` can be any iterable container of `int`, even an array. Returns via reference parameter into the input string.

```cpp
[](auto&s,auto&x){auto t=s;for(int i:x)t+="\n"+s.erase(i,1);s=t;}
```

no trailing newline: -5 byte

#### previous 70 byte solution

```cpp
[](auto&s,auto&x){auto t=s+'\n';for(int i:x)t+=s.erase(i,1)+'\n';s=t;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3BCoMwEETv@YqlhZpgWmrpqTH@iPUQYpSAJuJGEMRvt1GhsLDDm9lZPQz3Vuvtap3uptrk1mMYjeoL8kcRWNcWhKgpeGjkVlZ0lzfkx5rZcjhBYpp8XSIaP1LrAtjPzEIq8WFGhYZanrEzgDKIdROETBibwane4KC0AQx1pPttr6yjbCFwfgcECRfta9P6rrkIAntoLquIl4zD@5gnh9cavYYin1kU2k8B8hxQkHX7AQ)

The result is a single newline-seperated string.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/), 85 bytes

```cs
s=>a=>{for(int i=-2;++i<a.Count;)System.Console.WriteLine(s=i<0?s:s.Remove(a[i],1));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU5NS8NAEL3nVww9bWi6tMWT@RAJ6EVBquCh9LBsJmUg2dHMtiIhvz1uU6v0MQzDvMd7z8qiZcejMy3Kh7EIr9/isdVP5D6jPoIA2xgReJnu8@cE8caThSNTBc@GnIr/qH/RCQ8HZzPxHbl9AvfWE7us5KbB6RT9iA47siFRfEbOF0UBNeSj5IXJi77mToUvUL5Yp/M5ZUaXfHA@jX@blsGEG9TvHXkMtVFJTtnyTm5Fb7DlIyqzpV2yiuN0GNPoqlytZpYr3HNTz2Ll8AtC1nYHPawSuJlmmcAaBv3Gp4IqmFw7XOI3aKopPQgu3BCd9zD@AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 36 bytes

```
[ [ swap dup . remove-nth ] each . ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY@7DoJAEEV7vuKGHgPa@PgAY2NjrAjFugyPCDvr7qIxhG/HJWohTjOZc88tphDSsRnPp8Nxv4WwlqXFlYyiBtqQc09tauVg6daRkmRR8zffBUEfwE@PUFxk6HeMAcOM/ZOl937MmSY5p5KbolbllCQxNlhj5XvJpzeMKVLYh9DIO40FDLV8p0i5ChlIyMqzzEuq8bfkVrOl93vRlI4v)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 40 bytes

```ruby
F=->s,(a,*b){a&&(s[a]=""
puts s
F[s,b])}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWNzXcbHXtinU0EnW0kjSrE9XUNIqjE2NtlZS4CkpLihWKudyii3WSYjVr4eqj1ZPzU1LT83PSMvPS1XUUog0NdBQsdRQsdBSMdRSMdBQMdRQMYmMh6mH2AAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 32 bytes

**X** is takes as 1-indexed charcodes.

```
l:?!v1-{:o$!
ob0.>~ri:0(?;[{~]ra
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P8fKXrHMULfaKl9FkSs/yUDPrq4o08pAw946uroutijx/39uLk4WZibG/7rFyfkpqen5OWmZeekA)

Answer (score 0):

## R (+pryr), 45 bytes

Different (and longer) solution than @Guiseppe's.

```
f=pryr::f(`if`(sum(x|1),f(s[-x[1]],x[-1]),s))
```

which evaluates to the function:

```
function (s, x) 
if (sum(x | 1)) f(s[-x[1]], x[-1]) else s
```

Takes input as a list of characters and a list of 1-indexed indices. As long as `x` is not empty, recursively calls `f` with the first element from `x` removed, as well as its corresponding value in `s`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tampio](https://github.com/fergusq/tampio), 173 bytes

```
l miinus tyhjyys on l
l miinus a on l lisättynä l:ään avattuna a:lla
l avattuna a:lla lisättynä b:hen on l katkaistuna a:sta plus l jatkettuna a:n seuraajasta miinus b
```

Explanation:

```
l miinus tyhjyys on l
l -      []      =  l

l miinus a on l lisättynä l:ään avattuna a:lla
l -      a =  l :        (l     `avattu` a)

l avattuna  a:lla lisättynä b:hen on
l `avattu` (a     :         b)    =

  l katkaistuna a:sta plus l jatkettuna  a:n seuraajasta miinus b
((l `katkaistu` a)    ++  (l `jatkettu` (a   +1)     ) ) -      b
```

`katkaistu` and `jatkettu` are equivalent to `take` and `drop` of Haskell, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 29 bytes

```
f l{[l[:]];[l[:]]if del l[_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8pPSfz/P00hpzo6J9oqNtYaQmWmKaSk5ijkRMfH1v7PTczMU6jm4gxWsFWITs5ILCrWUErOT0lNz89JU9KM5eKMAEkY6iiYgJGBjoIRUDA6QkNToUYhTSNYMxZIFxRl5pVoxKspKWly1f4HAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 69 bytes

```go
func f(S string,X[]int){for _,i:=range X{S=S[:i]+S[i+1:];println(S)}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVDBSsQwFMRrvuLRU8u-le7qYe3S435BLoVSJMa2BNe0tOlBQr7ESxG8-UP6Nb42W5VdQ0jIZN7MMK9vdTN-tEI-ibqEZ6H0-2Cq9e7zUA1aQhVy6E2ndI1ZXihtIls1HdyjStJOaBrJLE95nqhixXO12iTFviW6OeqQR855sa-rg3lpS2gnrUEau4juIYNZ1jE2-00Bwggsk6Ive0hS-m4ts4FsHsu6OVYB-gG7Qbidd4ywdQ6JIx7kz3d8CV0iW4zxRDxjLXaU8deRnO4Qdgg3ZIlACeZhx3wlcorrS_HpLQPgmE2wvOZIR0bIUk-wphVEfxA-PahxzKJ_eI6d2hxHf38D)

Prints to STDERR.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
£{Ɗß
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDMiVBMyU3QiVDNiU4QSVDMyU5RiZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSdjb2RlZ29sZiclMEElNUIxJTJDJTIwNCUyQyUyMDQlMkMlMjAwJTJDJTIwMiU1RCZmbGFncz1l)

##### Explanation

```python
£{Ɗß  # Implicit input
£     # Print the first input
 {    # For each number in the second input:
  Ɗ   #   Drop the item at that index in the
      #   top of stack (initially first input)
   ß  #   Print this new string without popping
      #   (so we leave it for the next iteration)
```