# Exponentiation Sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence, number-theory

The oldest [Polish salt mine, located in Bochnia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochnia_Salt_Mine)*, was started in year 1248, which we can consider a *magical number*. We can see that it's equal to 4 digits from the sequence of exponentiations: [image: 2^0, 2^1, 2^2, 2^3].

As the date is actually 4 digits from the sequence, we could make it longer. We could repeat the process until we reach infinity. The sequence would look like this, if we limit it to number `2048`

```
124816326412825651210242048
```

To make it look a bit better, we can separate the numbers:

```
1|2|4|8|16|32|64|128|256|512|1024|2048
```

Let's try a custom, longer sequence than the date. Let's say, we want it to have 5 digits - there are more than one possibility:

- `24816`
- `81632`
- `64128`

Or 3 digit ones:

- `124`
- `248`
- `816`

We could also add the 3 digit numbers to this, but let's say, that a sequence must have **at least two numbers**.

<sup>* There is no information about this on the English Wikipedia. If you enter the Polish version - then there is. If you visit the mine, the workers will also tell you, that it started in 1248.</sup>

### The challenge

Create a exponentiation sequence like in examples above with 2 as the base.

Given a number from range 2-27, output **all possible** parts of the sequence (The 2048 one or larger if you want) with amount of digits equal to the input. You cannot cut a number, so output like `481` is invalid, because 16 is cut in half.

Rules:

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- You can assume the input is a number inside the range.
- Your program can accept inputs larger than the range (28+), but that won't increase/decrease score.
- Spaces in output are ignored. You can output like `124` or like `4 8 16`.
- Different possibilities should be separated by any character from the list: `,./|` or a line feed.
- You can output as an array.
- Every possibility should include **at least 2 different numbers**.
- You must output **a part** of the sequence, you cannot mix numbers that aren't next to each other, like: `14`.
- Hardcoded output isn't allowed, however, you can hardcode a string/number/array containing the full sequence.
- Input 27 should return the full 2048 sequence.
- As already mentioned before, **do not cut numbers**. Ex. `16` must stay `16` - you can't use `481` - you must use `4816`.
- **EDIT:** I might have said something wrong there; 2048 is the last number which your program should support, you can add support for larger int's.

### Test cases

Input: `2`

```
12, 24, 48
```

Input: `3`

```
124, 248, 816
```

Input: `4`

```
1248, 4816, 1632, 3264
```

Input: `5`

```
24816, 81632, 64128
```

Input: `27`

```
124816326412825651210242048
```

And later numbers...

If I made a mistake in any of the test cases, tell me or edit the question.

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: So this is only with 2 as the base, correct? Could you clarify that in the question? I'm not sure if it's implied by "Sequence of Exponentiations," but even if it is, I'm sure there are people out there like me who don't know that.

Comment: @cole Actually, yes, it's only with 2. Thanks for mentioning!

Comment: Can output be separated by newline?

Comment: @H.PWiz Actually, why not? Let me just edit the question.

Comment: I can't say that I don't keep upvoting every single answer here. The genius of people on ppcg is just amazing.

Comment: Does the output order matter?

Comment: @Shaggy No. You can output in any order you want.

Comment: Pushing my luck here but would [this](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=ScZJbyGy41ggbaxmX8qlVQqk&input=OAotUQ==) be an acceptable form of output?

Comment: @Shaggy No. I don't think I should allow it. I never seen anything output this way.

Comment: No worries; like I said, I was pushing it. Some challenge authors can be [incredibly flexible](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/138570/58974) on the output format so, for the sake of a byte or 2, it's worth asking ;) (Note: That should not be interpreted as a suggestion!)

Comment: You are missing `163264128256512102420484096` and `641282565121024204840968192` from the sequence generated from 27.

Comment: @kamoroso94 No, I'm not. I stated that if you want to support larger sequences than 2048, you can. But it's optional

Comment: In the intro, you should capitalize Polish.  ["polish" is a different English word](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polish).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>12</s> <s>11</s> 10 bytes

Supports the sequence up to `2^95 = 39614081257132168796771975168`

```
₃ÝoŒʒg≠}Jù
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f8wNWFiMWX//@KCg8Odb8WSypJn4omgfUrDuf//NTg)

**Explanation**

```
₃Ý            # push range [0 ... 95]
  o           # raise 2 to the power of each
   Œ          # get a list of all sublists
    ʒ         # filter, keep elements that satisfy:
     g        # length
      ≠       # false (not equal to 1)
       }      # end filter
        J     # join each
         ù    # keep numbers of length matching the input
```

Saved 1 byte thanks to *Erik the Outgolfer*
Saved 1 byte thanks to *Riley*

Comment: `X›` can be `≠`

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: Oh yeah. I always forget that one exist now. Thanks :)

Comment: Can `Y₃Ým` be `₃Ýo`?

Comment: @Riley: Yep. I had that before, but for some reason I must have changed it. Thanks :)

Comment: Trying the code now (much late after challenge end)... and your solution seems to return tons of empty arrays for me... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Soaku: Yeah, there have been a lot of changes to the language recently so old programs might not be compatible in all cases. If you want to run this code you can checkout an interpreter from the time of this challenge. You could also add `s` as the second last character to get this answer working in the new interpreter.

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, <s>22</s> <s>21</s> <s>20</s> 17 bytes

```
fqQlTjLkt#.:^L2yT
```

[Try it Online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fqQlTjLkt%23.%3A%5EL2yT&input=5&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
fqQlTjLkt#.:^L2yT
            ^L2yT  Get the powers of 2 up to 2^20
        t#.:       Get all consecutive sequences of at least 2
     jLk           Concatenate each
fqQlT              Get the ones whose length is the input
```

Comment: 21 bytes: `fqQlTmjkdftlT.:m^2d12`

Comment: [20 bytes - `fqQlTjLkftlT.:m^2d12`](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fqQlTjLkftlT.%3Am%5E2d12&input=5&debug=0)

Comment: 19 bytes - [fqQlTjLkftT.:m^2d12](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fqQlTjLkftT.%3Am%5E2d12&input=5&debug=0)

Comment: 18 bytes - [fqQlTjLkftT.:^L2yT](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fqQlTjLkftT.%3A%5EL2yT&input=5&debug=0)

Comment: 17 bytes - [fqQlTjLkt#.:^L2yT](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fqQlTjLkt%23.%3A%5EL2yT&input=5&debug=0)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>19 18</s>  16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>There may be a shorter solution now that we may use any cut-off (not just 2048), although this change to the specification has allowed a one byte save from this implementation by moving to a cut-off of 32768.

--yep...</sup>

-2 bytes thanks to [Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer) (use of `V` to allow implicit right argument of the filter and tightening)
--yes it is very similar to his inefficient one now; [go upvote his](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142574/53748)!

```
⁴Ḷ2*Ẇṫ17VDL$⁼¥Ðf
```

A monadic link taking a number and returning a list of numbers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//4oG04bi2MirhuobhuasxN1ZETCTigbzCpcOQZv///zU)**

#### How?

```
⁴Ḷ2*Ẇṫ17VDL$⁼¥Ðf - Link: number, n        e.g. 3
⁴                - literal sixteen             16
 Ḷ               - lowered range               [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
  2              - literal two                 2
   *             - exponentiate                [1,2,4,8,16,32,...,32768]
    Ẇ            - all sublists                [[1],[2],...,[1,2],[2,4],...,[1,2,4],...]
      17         - literal seventeen           17
     ṫ           - tail from index             [[1,2],[2,4],...,[1,2,4],...]]
        V        - evaluate as Jelly code      [12,24,...,124,...]
              Ðf - filter keep:
             ¥   -   last two links as a dyad
           $     -     last two links as a monad:
         D       -       decimal list (of entry) (i.e. 816 -> [8,1,6] or 24 -> [2,4])
          L      -       length                  (i.e. 816 -> 3, or 24 -> 2)
            ⁼    -   equals (n)                  (i.e. 816 -> 1, or 24 -> 0)
                 - ...resulting in             [816, 124, 248]
```

Comment: Is [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142574/41024) too similar to yours? (please be honest :p)

Comment: Funnily enough I was just trying to use `V` and it'll work for 16 rather than 1000: `⁴Ḷ2*Ẇṫ17VDL$⁼¥Ðf`.

Comment: I'm going for the most :p

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer they may now be similar but I am of the mind we should both keep them I'm sure you came up with yours independently and I'm sure I'd have found the eval trick too (since I was looking at exactly that, just needed to get the chaining right).

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I have made the assumption you are male, and prefer to be referred to as such, but actually do not know either as fact; do let me know if you prefer a different pronoun!

Comment: I will keep mine. Oh, and your assumption is correct, because I don't think "Erik" is a female name is it? ;p

Comment: Not normally, but one can never be 100% sure of these things :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>62</s> 59 bytes

```perl6
{grep *.comb==$_,map {[~] 2 X**[...] $_},combinations 12,2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCsIwEAXQtT3Fp8xCQxhwFrqQ9BxCKSFKIwXThNRNCfHqEd/6pTm/Ly3sIA/TyivPCYqfMTyMIauDSyjjd4LgrtTIzBPIVv0Py@o@S1w3nEVLbT5mCLNcUbrD5nb0ZGEGFPJHsqfa37rafg)

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>22</s> <s>20</s> <s>19</s> 16 bytes

Supports input up to `639` but gaps start appearing in the sequence after `234` (See the full list of supported input ranges [here](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=ScZJbyGy41ggbazDpGMgbcpuIPLIxDxZw6NbWGcgWMxd4iBxLQ==&input=LVI=)). Outputs an array of strings.

```
IÆIo!²ãX m¬lUÃ¤c
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=ScZJbyGy41ggbaxsVcOkYw==&input=NjM5Ci1R)

`I` (64) could be replaced with `L` (100) but we'd be getting into scientific notation and precision inaccuracies. Filtering those out would, obviously, increase the byte count and only raise the maximum input to `736`.

```
                     :Implicit input of integer U
I                    :64
 Æ                   :Map each X in [0,64)
  Io                 :  Range [0,64)
    !²               :  Raise 2 to the power of each
      ãX             :  Subsections of length X
         m           :  Map
          ¬          :    Join
           lU        :  Filter elements of length U
             Ã       :End map
              ¤      :Slice off the first 2 elements
               c     :Flatten
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

Output is separated by newlines

```
fo=⁰LmṁsftQ↑12¡D1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Py3f9lHjBp/chzsbi9NKAh@1TTQ0OrTQxfD///8mAA)

#### How?

```
           ↑12¡D1    The sequence [1,2,4...2048]
              ¡      Repeatedly apply function, collecting results in a list
               D     double
                1    initially applying to 1
           ↑12       Take the first 12 elements
          Q          Get all sublists
        ft           With a length greater than 1
     mṁs             Convert each list into a string, e.g [4,8,16] -> "4816"
fo=⁰L                Keep only those whose length is equal to the input
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 105 bytes

```python
lambda l,r=range:[x for x in[''.join(`2**n`for n in r(i,j+2))for i in r(13)for j in r(i,11)]if len(x)==l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NctBCsMgEIXhq8wumg4FDaUQ8CRGiKWxHbFjkCzs6W3TkuX7Hv/63p6ZdQtmasm/bncPCYspnh/LaCuEXKACse26c8zEYtZ9z/PO/GUogjCetJS70F/U8Fvx@JWSjgKkhUWVxiTXjtxqHPCC@urGtRBvwBgEy9Y@)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>72</s> 67 bytes

```hs
f n=[s|i<-[0..99],j<-[i+1..99],s<-[show.(2^)=<<[i..j]],length s==n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzza6uCbTRjfaQE/P0jJWJwvIzNQ2hHCKgZzijPxyPQ2jOE1bG5voTD29rNhYnZzUvPSSDIViW9u82P@5iZl5CrYKKflcnLmJBb4KGgVFmXklemmaCtFGenpG5rH/AQ)

*Saved 5 bytes thanks to Laikoni*

I used a limit of `99` because `2^99` has a length `> 27`.

Comment: It's returning extra cases for an input of 27 though.

Comment: You can replace 99 with 11, so it becomes *more* valid. Although, I did not state that numbers > 2048 are invalid. I stated only, that 2048 is the *minimum* range.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I think it's still correct: "The 2048 one or larger if you want" I took the 633825300114114700748351602688 sequence, because it guarantees that there won't be any other solution (in the range 2-27). Actually, I think a 45 limit would be sufficient, because `length$(show$2^44)++(show$2^45)==28`.

Comment: @jferard that was actually edited in *after* your answer (it actually stated "limited to 2048" before). I can shorten mine in this case too.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yes, I actually realised that some of rules in the question are wrong and misleading just after posting this anwer.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I wasn't cheating: I simply didn't see this limitation when I posted my answer! As Soaku stated, that does not change anything for my answer : `11` vs `99`.

Comment: @jferard yeah, I didn't think you were cheating :)

Comment: `s<-[show.(2^)=<<[i..j]]` saves some bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
ȷḶ2*ẆṫȷḊVDL$⁼¥Ðf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///E9oc7thlpPdzV9nDnahCnK8zFR@VR455DSw9PSPv//78RAA)

Note: very inefficient. Returns a list of numbers.

Comment: Tio doesn't seem to be able to parse this code... It always exceeds 60 seconds...

Comment: @Soaku Try [replacing the `ȷ`s (i.e. `1000`) with `20`s (lower upper limit)](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/I4OGObUZaD3e1Pdy5GsTpCnPxUXnUuOfQ0sMT0v4DFQAA).

Comment: @Soaku it works in theory - it just times out because it is very inefficient.

Comment: @ErikTheOutgolfer Then there is no output

Comment: @Soaku Did you follow my link? There *is* output there.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Weird. Not for me. I followed your link, replaced the J-thing with 20. And no output.

Comment: @Soaku I meant on my comment. I have already replaced them there, and there's output `[12, 24, 48]`.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Oh, sorry, did not notice the second ȷ

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer By the way, you can just simply replace those `J` with different Jelly built-in, since my challenge requires you to support **at least** the 2048 sequence.

Comment: @Soaku Why not go for the most if you can without extra cost? ;)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>102</s> 100 bytes

Prints all matching sub-sequences with `alert()`.

```js
l=>[...1e11+''].map((_,k,a)=>a.map((_,x)=>(s=(g=n=>x<=k|n<k?'':g(n-1)+2**n)(x)).length-l||alert(s)))
```

#### Demo

**NB**: This snippet is buffering the results and printing them to the console for user-friendliness.

```js
let f =

l=>[...1e11+''].map((_,k,a)=>a.map((_,x)=>(s=(g=n=>x<=k|n<k?'':g(n-1)+2**n)(x)).length-l||alert(s)))

alert = s => res += ' ' + s;

for(l = 2; l <= 27; l++) {
  res = '';
  f(l);
  console.log('L = ' + l + ' -->' + res);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 122 bytes

```
(s=#;FromDigits@F[f/@#]&/@Select[Subsequences[Array[2^#&,99,0]],l@#>1&&(l=Length)@(F=Flatten)[(f=IntegerDigits)/@#]==s&])&
```

**Input**

> [27]

**Output**

> {879609302220817592186044416, 134217728268435456536870912,
>   524288104857620971524194304, 163843276865536131072262144,
>   204840968192163843276865536, 256512102420484096819216384,
>   641282565121024204840968192, 163264128256512102420484096,
>   124816326412825651210242048}

```
Input [1000]
Output  1441151880758558722882303761517117445764607523034234881152921504606846976230584300921369395246116860184273879049223372036854775808184467440737095516163689348814741910323273786976294838206464147573952589676412928295147905179352825856590295810358705651712118059162071741130342423611832414348226068484722366482869645213696944473296573929042739218889465931478580854784377789318629571617095687555786372591432341913615111572745182864683827230223145490365729367654460446290980731458735308812089258196146291747061762417851639229258349412352483570327845851669882470496714065569170333976494081934281311383406679529881638685626227668133590597632773712524553362671811952641547425049106725343623905283094850098213450687247810566189700196426901374495621121237940039285380274899124224247588007857076054979824844849517601571415210995964968969903520314283042199192993792198070406285660843983859875843961408125713216879677197516879228162514264337593543950336158456325028528675187087900672316912650057057350374175801344
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, 170 bytes

```
i,j;f(n){char t[99],s[12][5]={"1"};for(i=j=1;i<12;)sprintf(s+i++,"%d",j*=2);for(i=0;i<12;++i,strlen(t)-n||j>1&&puts(t))for(j=*t=0;strlen(t)<n&&j+i<12;)strcat(t,s+i+j++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZDRbsMgDEXf8xUIaRHUVBpI09Q67EeyPERs2UCbWwF7SvPtGaRR/WRfH/le2R2/nFtXrwJOguTsvsfIcn86DSr12gz9y2BnrvmC0yUKb4PV6DttUKZr9JQnkcADKP70wVU4WCN38PmOAXiVcvz5JJHlkW638Kbb9vqXU5llRYM95EI/oI7aNsDukaMbs8iqmgQAictaTNnv6EnIZm5YqSoQbm25xwRZg4w6a16RAZDcNne01h67BD6/E1eMJD529QW4heN8l5dmWf8B)

**Unrolled:**

```
i,j;
f(n)
{
    char t[99], s[12][5] = {"1"};
    for (i=j=1; i<12;)
        sprintf(s+i++, "%d", j*=2);
    for (i=0; i<12; ++i, strlen(t)-n || j>1 && puts(t))
        for (j=*t=0; strlen(t)<n && j+i<12;)
            strcat(t, s+i+j++);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 33 bytes

```
{(x=#:')#,/{,/'$x':|2/=12}'2+!11}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLs6rWqLBVtlLXVNbRr9bRV1epULeqMdK3NTSqVTfSVjQ0rOXiSlMwAmJjIDYBYlMQ3xwAiFgMrQ==)

Generates all possible sublists, then selects those of the proper length. Returns a list of strings.

- `{...}'2+!11` generate 2..12 (the valid sublist lengths for input from 2..27), and run the code in `{...}` on each of those numbers

  - `|2/=12` generate the sequence `1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 2048`
  - `,/'$x':` take `x`-length rolling windows, converting each to strings, then concatenate them (e.g., `1 2 4 8` => `(1 2;2 4;4 8)` => `((,"1";,"2");(,"2";,"4");(,"4";,"8"))` => `("12";"24";"48")`)
- `(x=#:')#,/` flatten the potential strings, keeping those of the desired length

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 99 bytes

```r
function(n)for(i in 1:11)for(j in i:11+1)if(sum(nchar(x<-2^(0:11))[i:j])==n)cat(x[i:j],"\n",sep="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpLCoAgEADQq4irGSrI2kWepA@ENDRCU1hCt7ds@eCFRKqvEkVxNx8CgnQEYMWiTGfML5/FnwqDTHDFHcRtS4Cnr5oZ6vxw4M5PaK2gW254fpZ6FF1e62m1xkTQYnoB)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 76 bytes

75 bytes of code + 1 for `-a`

```perl
for$i(0..10){$/='',(map$/.=2**$_,$i..$_)&&$F[0]-length$/||say$/for$i+1..11}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8tv0glU8NAT8/QQLNaRd9WXV1HIzexQEVfz9ZIS0slXkclU09PJV5TTU3FLdogVjcnNS@9JENFv6amOLFSRR@sXdsQqN2w9v9/Yy5TLiPzf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDf7rJgIA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 94 bytes

```ruby
->n{a=*b=1;a<<b*=2until b>3**n;(2..n).flat_map{|x|a.each_cons(x).map &:join}.grep /^.{#{n}}$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LczRCoIwFADQXxkUoWNdcSJBOn9kLNlEy7DrMIXF3LevHno9D2fZzCcOIp4b9FpQI/JK17Whgm@4jhMxTUEpVgkHwBSGSa/tS1u/u11Dr7tH2834TlwKPyWn63MeMcB96S3JbuAPHkM4ZiFKzgpWsrxk/KLgP1giHRukUyrE@AU)